# Eigen: Numpy like element indexing

Tags: c++, numpy, eigen

Is there easy way to modify specific elements in Eigen matrix?

For example, what is the fastest way doing the following assignment in Eigen?

```
# a typical numpy code
mat[mat > 0] = 0;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you looking something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728341/coefficient-wise-custom-functions-in-eigen ?

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25766754/2899559).

Comment: Thanks, select seems to be the correct answer. My specific question could be solved by (mat.array() > 0).select(0, mat) in Eigen. But unfortunately, this expression seems to run similar performance with expression using "for". Anyway thank you @Avi.

Comment: Thanks @Gluttton, it is another option to select. But I'm not sure it if performance-wise or not.

Comment: Select is not (yet?) vectorized. It may be in the future, but we'll have to wait for the devs to give a timeframe if relevant.

Comment: You mean by vectorized, for performance-wise operation? Because it works for matrix.array() without any problem.

Comment: Yes, I mean SIMD when I say vectorized. It works fine with the expressions, it's just that the performance boost from utilizing SSE/AVX type engines has not been added yet.

Answer (score 0):

*An old question but it may still help you or others.* Now there are more (and depending on the situation probably better) ways to do what you ask, as opposed to when you posted your question.

As of Eigen version 3.4-rc1 you can use Slicing.
Take a look at the [documentation section 'Slicing and Indexing'](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html).

Comment: It seems that we cannot perform inplace modification using slices